# Как преобразовать миллисекунды в дату формата : DD-MM-YY(и время) в файле csv? Python-3

Tags: python, дата, csv

Нужны Ваши помощь и совет. Проблема заключается в следующем: имеется файл в формате .csv, в нем имеется столбец с датой, но указанной в миллисекундах. Можно было б перевести вручную, онлайн переводчиком, но в столбце этом около 2000 строк. Возможен ли скрипт на Python, который переведет миллисекунды в обычный формат даты: дни-месяцы-годы : время, прямо извлекая их из csv и кладя обратно в столбец по порядку? Спасибо всем большое.

Comment: Да, возможен, конечно.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Можете им поделиться? Уже второй день рою интернет, не могу найти то, что подходит (в основном проблема извлечения из csv).

Comment: Если вы исправите свой вопрос так, чтобы он не нарушал правила сайта, а именно - приложите в вопрос свои попытки решить задачу, то вам наверняка помогут.

Comment: Как пояснял - я новичок в Python.Только книгу "Укус Питона" прошел. Опыта в редактировании csv через скрипт -  нет.  Попытки решить задачу - двухдневные поиски решения, безвылазно зависая в интернете, в надежде найти хоть что-нибудь похожее. Хотя б направление дать бы мне, куда смотреть, где читать об этом...

Comment: Запрос `"python date from seconds"` сравзу выводит на https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140121/7286264 Остается разделить миллисекунды на 1000. (Подозреваю, что с csv ситуация аналогичная)

Comment: Почитал. Суть задачи немного другая : имеется csv файл, в нем 10 строк, и в каждой строке около 2000 столбцов. Цель : преобразовать строки первого столбца со временем в миллисекундах, в строки с датой, указанного мною формата , не нарушая изначального порядка (не путая очередность строк), в самом файле csv - скрипт извлекает, меняет и кладет обратно ( ну или изменяет внутри). Вся проблема в этом.

Comment: И опять, несколько секунд поиска по запросу "python csv" и пара минут [чтения](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) выводят на `class csv.DictReader`, для которого даже пример использования есть

Comment: Спасибо. Поищу еще.

Comment: @SadRain, imho пора прекратить поиски и начать писать код

Comment: Уже пытаюсь. Что-то вроде получается. Спасибо еще раз.